# Set the default parameter value for the report by code

Tags: java, crystal-reports, business-objects, business-objects-sdk

all my crystal report are publish on my business object server.

all of them are connected to Business Views Object.

all of these Business Views use the same dynamic Data Connection.

This make that my report have this Dynamic Data Connection Parameter.

I can change this parameter via the Central Management Console.

But now I would like to be able to change it via code with the BO's SDK.

I have this method that I think is near achieving what i want , I just can save the changes.

```
        public static void updateParameter(IInfoObject report){

    // get all parameters
    try {
        IReport rpt = (IReport) report;
        int i = 0;
        IReportParameter params;
        for(i=0;i<rpt.getReportParameters().size();i++){
            params = (IReportParameter) rpt.getReportParameters().get(i);
            int y = 0;
            for(y=0;y<params.getCurrentValues().getValues(IReportParameter.ReportVariableValueType.STRING).size();y++){
                IParameterFieldDiscreteValue val = (IParameterFieldDiscreteValue) params.getCurrentValues().getValues(IReportParameter.ReportVariableValueType.STRING).getValue(y);
                if(val.getDescription().contains("Data Connection")){
                    val.setValue(boConstance.conn_EXAMPLE1);
                    val.setDescription(boConstance.desc_EXAMPLE1);
                    //save the new parameter ?????
                    System.out.println("report parameters modified");
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (SDKException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Any Idea ? Thanks,

Comment: found what I wanted look at : [link](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/boc/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/b0e87da0-833f-2b10-f2a7-a3c5b00008ea?QuickLink=index&overridelayout=true&30949534351040)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already setting the parameters you should just need to call the save method on the IReport itself.  You wouldn't save the parameters directly since they are data belonging to the report.

So to finish your example after the for loop

```
try {
    IReport rpt = (IReport) report;
    int i = 0;
    IReportParameter params;
    for(i=0;i<rpt.getReportParameters().size();i++){
        // do for loop here setting the parameters
    }

    rpt.save();
} catch (SDKException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Can't make this work.. I think I wasn't clear enough. I don't want to set the parameter to after schedule the report. I want to update de default parameter that you can find on the CMC (Folder -> myFolder -> myPubliedReport / Tab Process - Parameters